# Mysql Rank with a Where clause will be faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database with 8.000.000 rows, with 2 columns 'id' and 'score', i know also the exact number of users with score=0 (that is near 4.000.000).

I've a ranking board in my webpage with the query:

```
"SELECT id, score FROM table ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ".$num_rank.", 25"
```

`$num_rank` defines which page show, and it's 25 users per page.

The query works, and it show what it has to show but the problem is that the query is really slow.

The question is the next query may be faster?:

```
$num_users_score_0 = 4000123

if(score==0){  
$num_rank=$num_rank-$num_users_score_0  
query=**"SELECT id, score FROM table WHERE score = 0 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ".$num_rank.", 25"**  
}else{  
query=**"SELECT id, score FROM table WHERE score > 0 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT ".$num_rank.", 25"**  
}
```

All suggestions are appreciatted!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your queries will be faster, with one improvement to the first:  the `order by is unnecessary:

```
query="SELECT id, score FROM table WHERE score = 0 LIMIT ".$num_rank.", 25"
```

ALso, this will be faster with an index on `table(score, id)`.  In fact, with this index, you may be able to use your original query.